# generating orthogonal parity check matrix, from a random generator matrix

Tags: matrices, coding-theory

I have a matrix G of dimension 13x20. It is a full rank matrix. It is not in the standard form of a generator matrix. Now for the parity check matrix 'H', I need a standard representation H=[-P;I].

I used gauss Jordan elimination method, to convert 'G' into standard form, and the resulting matrix, is orthogonal with H matrix. But the H matrix, is not orthogonal to the G matrix.

So I did G*H1=[0]. and solved a system of linear equations to find the H1 that is orthogonal to the g matrix, I wass able to find only one vector, but for the remaining vecors, while solving the system of linear equations, the system is inconsistent(solution does not exist).

Because I was able to find a matrix from G that is orthogonal to H, why am I not able to find a H1 that is orthogonal to G?

Are there some mathematical methods available to do this??

regards,
phani tej

Comment: Doing elementary row operations to $G$ does not change its property of being ortogonal to $H$. So either you made a mistake, or you also performed some other kind of operations. Are you aware of the fact that you may also need to do column permutations to put a generator matrix into standard form? Column permutations WILL destroy orthogonality. Not all codes have a generator/check matrix in standard form unless you are prepared to do column permutations. But if you do, then you will change the code, and need to the same column permutations to the original code to preserve orthgonality.

Comment: supposing i have a G which is not in standard form, I encode my bits with the G. Now how to recover my bits. will there be two matrices, one for error correction, and after correcting them, how to decode my original data?

Comment: I describe the process for finding $H$ in [my answer to your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1348216/11619).