# Can the housholder transformation be determined in $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

I have a linear system of equations in $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$ which I currently solve with Gaussian elimination. However, due to several reasons my current implementation now requires an alternative approach to solve the linear system of equations.

My first alternative approach amounts to the Householder transformation. Thereby, I noticed that the calculation of the norm of the currently observed column is necessary. In my first, naive implementation I used the euclidean norm to calculate the respective norm. Nevertheless, I realized that this yields invalid divisions by zero such that I fail to eliminate the linear system of equations through Householder matrices.

An answer that was given in  [How to find orthogonal vectors in GF(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346664/how-to-find-orthogonal-vectors-in-gf2) stated that that the Gramm-Schmidt orthogonalization method is not possible in $\operatorname{GF}(2)$. For this reason I am wondering whether the Householder transformation in $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$ is also not possible because of the missing norm for vectors.

Thank you in advance for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the nonexistence of a suitable norm is the most significant problem. The fact that you can have $\langle v,v\rangle=0,$ with the vector $v\neq 0$ is another problem, if that vector is the normal vector of the plane you want to reflect about.

More fundamentally, this is a *discrete* space, so ideas of convergence from reals or complex numbers don't carry over.

Curious, why exactly do you want to not do Gaussian elimination? And what is the application you are looking at, if you don't mind sharing. $GF(2^8)$ to me suggests maybe cryptography?

Comment: Thank your for your reply. For my current work, a system of equations in GF(2^8) has to be solved. However, this must be done in such a way that no information is visible in the power side channel. Gaussian Elimination causes a lot of leakage, so I'm now looking for alternative solution strategies.

Comment: I see. I suggest you ask at crypto.stackexchange and give the background. and details, how many equations, unknowns etc.

Comment: Sorry for the maybe stupid question. Is it possible to solve the system of equations using an iterative method (SOR, Gauss-Seidel method, Jacobi method)? As you explained "this is a discrete space, so ideas of convergence from reals or complex numbers don't carry over". From that I would conclude that iterative methods won`t work as well since in GF(2^8) there is no "close" in the sense of real numbers.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: @RatbaldMeyer Seconding kodlu's advice. [Cryptopeople](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions) have more experience in masking calculations in a way that does not leak information via ppower consumption. This particular problem does not ring a bell (at me), but it is very possible that somebody has considered it satisfactorily.